# Matter beyond event horizon

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, symmetry, antimatter, time-reversal-symmetry

Assuming that antimatter is matter with time arrow reversed, would it be right to say that matter beyond black hole event horizon then would become antimatter because of space and time axes exchanged? Would not black hole then appear like a nice universe consisting from antimatter that slowly expands as matter falls into it?

I do not claim anything just want to find out how wrong the idea is. Although, it is not really related to the question but I would like shortly explain where from my crazy idea that matter can indeed move to the opposite time direction is coming. I think that there was no Big Bang but initially was space filled with matter fluctuating back and forth in time (field fluctuating between matter and antimatter). 
Since there was no real matter - matter and antimatter fluctuated from vacuum and annihilated chaotically and hence there were no state transitions (movement) which we perceive as time - there was no time, in fact there was no matter either - just vacuum. 
But at some random event indicated as 'shortly after Big Bang', CP-symmetry got broken, which caused antimatter to disappear and gave rise to the time which we since perceive as going forward (if by some other event antimatter had won our time would go into opposite direction - but this does not mean 'back in time'). CP-violation caused universe expansion, but there was no initial rapid expansion, since universe did not arise from a singularity, but from a homogeneous space, which is in sync with recent Cosmic background radiation observations.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, Antimatter is not really moving in the opposite direction of time but this is not the only problem.

I guess your question comes from a straightforward interpretation of the Schwarzschild Metric, well the singularity you're considering is not a primordial singularity and with a wise substitution you can make it disappear. This is just a mathematical artifact that has nothing to do with physics considerations. It allows you to define the Schwarzschild radius and predict blackholes but it doesn't tell you what's happening inside. So I guess your interpretation is still possible but not under this assumption.

Comment: I did not mean antimatter moving back in time. I meant that matter moving back in time exhibit antimatter properties. You know - Feynman diagrams.

Comment: You know Feynman diagrams are not just drawings, Matter is not moving back in time, the arrow direction is just an elegant way to help you write the correct mathematical contraction but you should not interpret it physically. It's a tool to vulgarize a heavy mathematical background. Furthermore, Antimatter is not a mirror image under parity but under charge conjugation. And this is without considering the C and P violations. I think I didn't get your question, maybe you should clarify.

Comment: You are right I should not have mentioned parity or 'mirror image'. Matter going backwards in time did not change parity. It is antimatter moving forward in time has opposite parity to matter.
Also, I edited question providing some clarification. 
Thanks